# How to access a nested field in json with Laravel?

Tags: php, json, rest, laravel

Hello I need to access to a nested field within a json file. I am using Laravel 5 and I have this in controller:

```
public function getLanguages($id){
    $user=User::find($id);

    if (!$user)
    {
       return response()->json(['errors'=>array(['code'=>404,'message'=>'No se encuentra un usuario con ese código.'])],404);
    }

    return Response::make(json_encode($user->languages), 200)->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');

}
```

This is the output:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Español",
    "pivot": {
      "id_user": 1,
      "id_language": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Inglés",
    "pivot": {
      "id_user": 1,
      "id_language": 2
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Alemán",
    "pivot": {
      "id_user": 1,
      "id_language": 3
    }
  }
]
```

I want to access to the name of languages that a user has, how can I do that? This is a many to many relationship between User and Language, is better access to the languages trough the User model? or access from the pivot table?

Thanks.

Comment: You mean you want to get a json contains only language's name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
        $user       =   User::find($id)->languages->toArray();
        $languages  =   array_column($user, 'name');  

        return Response::make(json_encode($languages), 200)->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `$user->languages` is an array containing the languages, you could use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), e.g.

```
function extract_name($el) {
    return $el['name'];
}

$names = array_map('extract_name', $user->languages);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am obtaining this error:

ErrorException in UserController.php line 153:
array_map() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'extract_name' not found or invalid function name

I did put the function before and after of the method which I am calling, but no works

Comment: Definitly it does not work because array_map function needs an array in second parameter, and $user->languages is not a simple array, is an array with arrays in any fields, i dont understand what kind of type is $user->languages

Comment: I tested this in a simple script with an array of arrays, so it should work. And your JSON output indicates an array of dictionaries.

Comment: userController is a class you should declare it like                                    $names = array_map(array($this, "extract_name"), $user->languages);

Comment: If you declare `extract_name` as a method of UserController, you're right of course.